# Jquery Add string from button value into an input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to add some string from button that has a value into an input field but doesn't work ..

here's jquery code, can anyone please fix it ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#kategori');
        text.val(text.val() + $('#button1')(text.val());    
    });
});
</script>
```

and here html + php code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="kategori">
Kategori:
</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="kategori" name="kategori" />
</div>

<?php $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from kategori_elibrary"); 
$hasil = $query->result();

?>

<div class="btn-group">

<?php
        foreach($hasil as $row){

 echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" value="'.$row->kategori.'">'.$row->kategori.'</button>';
   } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: what value are you storing in button ? $row->kategori what it returns ?

Comment: better use data-attribute for the button to store that $row->kategori

Comment: put script inside foreach loop

Comment: @billy try below given answer , but write you button click event on class (don't use ID attribute) , and store your $row->kategori value to data-attribute. make this two change to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: answer below is work, but only work on first button on foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of data-attributes which makes the button markup look like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" data-value="Food">
    Food
</button>
```

Then you can use this script: **UPDATED**

```js
// NOTE: This will get all button elements of type button
// if you have other elements of this markup change the selector to:
// $('button[id^="button"]')
$('button:button').on('click', function() {
    var $target = $('#kategori'),
     text = $('#kategori').val(),
        buttonVal = $(this).data('value');
    $target.val(`${text}${buttonVal}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="kategori">
        Kategori:
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kategori" name="kategori" />
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" data-value="Food">Food</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button2" data-value="Tools">Tools</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button2" data-value="Anything">Anything</button>
```

Comment: the answer is work, but only work on first button on foreach loop. Is there anyway to work on next button ?

Comment: does each button target the same input text?

Comment: no, every button has their own value, based on '.$row->kategori.'

Comment: i meant do they target the same input element?? like in the above example target only the input of id `kategori` ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you need like this: button text added into textbox at the time of click.apply `$(this).html()` button value add to texbox

```js
    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
       $('#kategori').val($('#kategori').val()+$(this).html());
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="kategori">
Kategori:
</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="kategori" name="kategori" />
  <button id="button1">before</button>
</div>



<div class="btn-group">


</div>
```

***Alternate***

if you create the button like

```
`<input type="button" id="button1" value="before">
```

in jquery use with. `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#button1').on('click', function () {
    $('#kategori').val($('#kategori').val() + $('#button1').attr('value'));    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="kategori">
Kategori:
</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="kategori" name="kategori" />
</div>


<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button1" value="1">1</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#button1').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#kategori');
        text.val(text.val() + $('#button1').val());    
    });
});
</script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="button2" value="2">2</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#button2').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#kategori');
        text.val(text.val() + $('#button2').val());    
    });
});
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( '.button-input' ).on( 'click', function () {

    $( '#kategori' ).val( $(this).val() );

} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="kategori">Kategori:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kategori" name="kategori" />
</div>

<?php 
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from kategori_elibrary");

    $hasil = $query->result();
?>

<div class="btn-group">

<?php   foreach ( $hasil as $row ) { ?>

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-input" id="button<?= $row->id; ?>" value="<?= $row->kategori; ?>" />
    
<?php   } ?>    

</div>
```